# Keras convolution along single feature row

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a multiclass classification problem. Say I have a feature matrix:

```
A   B C D
1  -1 1 -6
2 0.5 0 11
7 3.7 1 1
4 -50 1 0
```

And labels:

```
LABEL
0
1
2
0
2
```

I want try to apply convolution kernels along each single feature row with Keras. Say nb_filter=2 and batch_size=3. So I expect input shape for convolution layer to be (3, 4) and output shape to be (3, 3) (as it is applied for AB, BC, CD).

Here what I tried with Keras (v1.2.1, Theano backend):

```
def CreateModel(input_dim, num_hidden_layers):
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Convolution1D, Flatten

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=10, filter_length=1, input_shape=(1, input_dim), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    return model

def OneHotTransformation(y):
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    return np_utils.to_categorical(y)

X_train = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]),
y_train = OneHotTransformation(y_train)

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=CreateModel, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], num_hidden_layers=1, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=500)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Shapes:

```
print X_train.shape
print X_test.shape
print y_train.shape
```

Output:

```
(45561, 44)
(11391, 44)
(45561L,)
```

When I try to run this code I get and exception:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (45561L, 3L)
```

I tried to reshape y_train:

```
y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0], 1, y_train.shape[1])
```

This gives me exception:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (136683L, 2L)
```

1. Is this approach with Convolution1D correct to achieve my goal?
2. If #1 is yes, how can I fix my code?

I've already read numerous github issues and some questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364415/keras-building-a-network-for-9-dimensional-feature-vector), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656566/input-dimensions-to-a-one-dimensional-convolutional-network-in-keras?rq=1)) here, but it didn't really help.

Thanks.

**UPDATE1:**
According to Matias Valdenegro comment.
Here are shapes after reshaping 'X' and after onehot encoding for 'y':

```
print X_train.shape
print X_test.shape
print y_train.shape
```

Output:

```
(45561L, 1L, 44L)
(11391L, 1L, 44L)
(45561L, 3L)
```

**UPDATE2:** Thanks again to Matias Valdenegro. X reshaping is done after creating model for sure it was a copy paste issue. The code should look like:

```
def CreateModel(input_dim, num_hidden_layers):
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Convolution1D, Flatten

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=10, filter_length=1, input_shape=(1, input_dim), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    return model

def OneHotTransformation(y):
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    return np_utils.to_categorical(y)

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=CreateModel, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], num_hidden_layers=1, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=500)

X_train = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]),
y_train = OneHotTransformation(y_train)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

The input to a 1D convolution should have dimensions (num_samples, channels, width). So that means you need to reshape X_train and X_test, not y_train:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])
```

Comment: As you can see in my question, I tried without reshaping y_train. And it also throws exception.

Comment: @shda The shapes in your question do not match to what is expected after a reshape, are you sure they are right?

Comment: Sorry, these were shapes before reshaping. I'll update my question.

Comment: @shda Make sure he input dims are correct, it should be (1, 44).

Comment: Where should I check it? input_dim variale in CreateModel is equal to 44 at runtime. So input_shape for Convolution1D is (1, 44).

Comment: @shda Inside CreateModel, from the code that is in the question currently, you are passing X_train.shape[1], which after reshape is 1. Also I believe the filter length should not be 1, try with 2.

Comment: Reshaping is done after model creation. It was a copy paste issue. Thanks. Also I Tried with filter_length=2. No changes. The same exception is raised: "ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (45561L, 3L)"